# webpack file-loader options aren't recognized

Tags: reactjs, webpack, loader, webpack-style-loader

Being new to webpack, the answer might be staring me down but I don't see it. No matter how I try to pass them along, the file-loader options aren't found.

I'm using file-loader and I'm trying to pass a publicPath (or simply anything, at first) along as an option. I went into the file loader source code and added a log for all the options it detected, but they always come up empty.

**webpack.config.prod.js**

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')


module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'idlink-1.1.1.js',
    publicPath: ''
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"production"'})
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: { presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1'] }
      },
      {test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" },
      {test: /\.scss$/, loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]},
      {test: /\.less$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader!less-loader" },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|pdf)$/i,
        loader: "file",
        options: { publicPath: 'https://apps.ixordocs.be/'}
      },
      {test: /\.gif$/, loader: "url-loader?mimetype=image/png" }
    ]
  },
}
```

I've also tried with 
`loader: "file-loader"`

as well as added the options as one string like this

`loader: "file?name=[name].[ext]&publicPath=https://apps.ixordocs.be/"`

Some context info: 
I don't want to have a hardcoded publicPath defined in my `output: {}`, i want to grab it dynamically from a parameter placed on the div that my plugin is loaded into.

I've tried using the `__webpack_public_path__` variable and it works, but not for images. The public path is grabbed from the parameter, set, and used to fetch a chunk. Somehow it has no effect on images though. If I hardcode a publicPath under output, it DOES work for images. This leads me to believe there is a problem with the loader's communication to the variable, so the idea is to get the options working and eventually try to pass a dynamic publicPath in there.

Comment: For one I don't see any example or documentation that suggests you can put an url into publicPath, it is always a local file system path. This does not seem to be the tool to solve your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I was afraid of this as well, so i did also try it with a local path. Unfortunately it's not only path-related options that aren't found. Simply no options are being passed through.

Comment: Perhaps a silly question but... did you actually install the file-loader module?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is totally valid based on the documentation of the loader on both loader's [GitHub repo](https://github.com/webpack/file-loader) and [webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/). The problem is the `publicPath` and `outputPath` features are implemented in a [pull request](https://github.com/webpack/file-loader/pull/81) that is merged but not yet released to a new version of loader, and the [README](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-loader) on npm doesn't mention the features for the same reason.
You can still use these features by installing from the GitHub repo with `npm install webpack/file-loader --save-dev` and your options should work. If not try replacing `options` with `query`.

```
{
    test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|pdf)$/i,
    loader: "file-loader",
    query: { publicPath: 'https://apps.ixordocs.be/'}
}
```

Using URLs for `publicPath` is also valid because it happens often that you want to load your assets from a CDN or another server.